# Combine Spreadsheets with different columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, combine

Two workbooks listing unique identifiers but with different column names/parameters. 
How to combine them to produce one sheet with all the columns for each identifier on the lists? Iradicating duplicates.
The same unique identifiers mostly occur in both spreadsheets.

Comment: Please proved some sample data from both worksheets together with a sample solution and what you have already tried. It sounds fairly simply but without sample data any solution wont make sense.

Comment: 1510125 Sweden  Jonkoping 15561
1510126  USA       MMS   15920

1510128 Ziekenhuis Nij Smellinghe Ziekenhuis Nij Smellinghe  Drachten 19196
1510129 MMS USA Inc.    15920

Comment: 1)Identifier, Country, City,Product#                                                             1510125 Sweden  Jonkoping 15561
1510126  USA       MMS   15920
1510128 Netherlands Ziekenhuis  19196                                                 2) Identifier,Date,PO#,                                                                            
1510125  01/22/16  9378016                                                         1510126 05/27/17  8976456                                                        1510128 08/2

Comment: Very very difficult in this comment box but I have two sheets with the same "identifiers" but with different columns. I want 1 sheet with all columns. listing all 12000 identifiers but with the data from all columns in the combined sheet.

Comment: I don't understand how Index and/or Match can help?

Comment: Please edit your question. Adding extra information in unformatted comments does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Without anything to go on, I would suggest using INDEX() and MATCH() to copy into a third workbook from both source ones using a common identifier.